# SQL Command datareader while loop not working

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, while-loop

I Have a question regarding SQL commands. I could not seems to get the while loop running under the "while(dr.read())". Below Are my sample code in C# Windows Form.
Thank You.

```
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM network";
                MySqlDataReader dr;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string datasource = dr[1].ToString();
                    string datadestination = dr[2].ToString();
                    if (source == datasource && destination == datadestination)
                    {
                        int newcounter;
                        newcounter = Convert.ToInt32(dr[4]) + 1;
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE network set counter = @nnnewcounter";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nnnewcounter", newcounter);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO network(source,destination,length,counter) VALUES (@sssource,@dddestination,@lllength,@cccounter)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sssource", source);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dddestination", destination);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lllength", length);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cccounter", 1);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: error ? tried placing breakpoint ? exiting loop ?

Comment: Did you get an exception, f.e. that you have to open the connection?

Comment: not error nor exception its just that there is no data inserted in the database

Comment: best way to find errors is placing breakpoints..

Comment: i do not know how to use breakpoints sry

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

This link contains example code of how to use a `DataReader`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with this first you’re reusing the same command and using different parameters at which point you should clear them.  It is also not clear if your are Opening the connection for the datareader.  I would therefore move the insert and update outside the SQLDataReader as it would make the code easier to read.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM network";
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
             if (dr .HasRows)
             {
                  while (dr.Read())
                  {
                    string datasource = dr[1].ToString();
                    string datadestination = dr[2].ToString();
                    if (source == datasource && destination == datadestination)
                    {
                        int newcounter;
                        newcounter = Convert.ToInt32(dr[4]) + 1;
                        Updateddos_network(newcounter);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Savedoss_network(source,destination, length, 1);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
               //No rows found
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Then outside the method in the same class you could have.

```
            private void Updateddos_network(int newcounter)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                   using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                   {
                     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ddos_network set counter = @nnnewcounter";
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nnnewcounter", newcounter);
                     cmd.Connection.Open();
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
                }
            }


            private void Insertddos_network(string source, string destination, int length, int counter)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                   using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                   {
                     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ddos_network(source,destination,length,counter) VALUES (@sssource,@dddestination,@lllength,@cccounter)";
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sssource", source);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dddestination", destination);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lllength", length);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cccounter", counter);
                     cmd.Connection.Open();
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
                }
            }
```

If you were to refactor your code further you could have a Save method for your ddos_network object which could then be used to demine if your object is being updated or inserted based upon if the current object has an Id for example.